# Armazenar imagem(jpg) em uma variável - Delphi

Tags: delphi

Estou com uma dúvida em relação a armazenar uma imagem em uma variável no Delphi. Estou utilizando uma função que salva como imagem uma assinatura coletada em um coletor de assinatura digital (Step Over - naturaSign). Porém, esta função apenas salva a imagem em um diretório da minha máquina. Gostaria de saber como faço para ir até o caminho do diretório, pegar essa imagem e finalmente armazená-la em uma variável. Desde já agradeço as respostas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A classe `TPicture` tem o procedimento `LoadFromFile` para carregar uma imagem, para utiliza-la seria mais ou menos assim:

```
function CarregarImagem(caminhoImagem: String): TPicture;
var
  picture: TPicture;
begin
  picture := TPicture.Create();
  picture.LoadFromFile(caminhoImagem);
  Result := picture;
end;
```

Para utilizar o método basta passar onde se localiza a imagem:

```
var
  picture: TPicture;
begin
  picture := CarregarImagem('C:\teste.jpg');
end;
```

> A classe `TPicture` é localizada na unit `Graphics`

Comment: Muito obrigado meu amigo. Ajudou bastante!

Comment: `TPicture.Create;`

Comment: Classe "TGraphic" também tem procedimento "LoadFromFile ()" não função

Comment: @Sami, obrigado por me corrigir na questão da nomeação. Na questão dos `()`, eu gosto de utiliza-los para deixar claro que é um procedimento, existe algum tipo de problema utilizar desta forma?